# TIdMessage - Attachments Show Up in Body of email as text when using IMAP AppendMessage

Tags: delphi, imap, attachment, indy

I am sending an email using Indy 10 SMTP. That part is working fine. I then attempt to use Indy IMAP to save the sent message into a folder, for example "Drafts".

When there is one PDF attachment, the Draft email does not contain the attachment, instead the body appears to be the Base64 encoded version of the attachment. If there are two PDF attachments, both are saved correctly with the email in the Drafts folder.

I tried adding two attachments, then deleting the last one (as a hacky work around) but the result is the same as if i'd sent only one attachment.

```pascal
idMBHTML := TIdMessageBuilderHTML.Create;
Idmessage1 := TIDMessage.Create;

try
  with idMBHTML do
  begin
    //enc := TEncoding.Unicode;
    HTML.Assign(slOBodyMessage);

    Attachments.Add('pdf_1_3.pdf');
    Attachments.Add('pdf_1_4.pdf');
    FillMessage(IDMessage1);
  end;

  with Idmessage1 do
  begin
    Subject := sOSubject;
    From.Address := sOSenderEmail;
    From.Name := sOSenderName;
    for t := 0 to slORecipients.count -1 do
      with Recipients.Add do
        Address := slORecipients[t];
    with ReplyTo.Add do
      Address := sOReplyToEmailAddress;
  end;

  with IDSMTP1 do
  begin
    if not Connected then
      Connect;
    Send(IdMessage1);
  end;
```

The IMAP code is:

```pascal
IdIMAP41:= TIdIMAP4.create;
try
  IdIMAP41.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
  IdIMAP41.Host := sIMAPServer;
  IdIMAP41.Password := sOPassword;
  IdIMAP41.Port := StrToInt(sPOPIMAPPort);

  IdIMAP41.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
  IdIMAP41.Username := sOUserName;

  IdIMAP41.Connect;

  IdIMAP41.SelectMailbox(sPOPIMAPFolder); //eg Drafts
  IdIMAP41.AppendMsg(sPOPIMAPFolder,Info);
  IdIMAP41.Disconnect;

  Result := True;
finally
  FreeAndNil(IdIMAP41);
end;
```

I am using GMail as my provider, but I've tested with with others and get the same result.

Using Delphi Seattle.

---

**UPDATE:**

Yes, `IdMessage1` and `info` are the same.

Delphi is Seattle, Indy is 10.6.2.5298 (the included version)

I added the logging components and indeed the header is malformed for the IMAP.

I have now totally separated my SMTP and IMAP code, in that `IdMessage1` is now created from scratch for IMAP.

Here is `IdMessage1.LastGeneratedHeaders.Text` for 1 attachment:

```
From: "Sertest 3" 
Subject: Sertest 3
To: xxx@xxx.com.au, xxx@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Reply-To: replytome@gmail.com
Date: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 12:45:05 +1000
```

And here is the same for an email with two attachments:

```
From: "Sertest 3" 
Subject: Sertest 3
To: xxx@xxx.com.au, xxx11@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="lAqexjggOIhYhFY4iWo=_1kYl1dH8lWpUP"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Reply-To: replytome@gmail.com
Date: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 12:49:05 +1000
```

Interestingly, I used two copies of the same file as the two attachments, and it only showed up in Gmail as a single attachment.  So, it seems I have a short term workaround, although I would rather not.

For completeness, here is my IMAP code now:

```pascal
function SaveMail(EmailSendOptions : TEmailSendOptions): Boolean;
var
  IdIMAP41:TIdIMAP4;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Attachment: TIdAttachmentFile;
  t: integer;
  Idmessage1 : TIDMessage;
begin
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create;
  try
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Destination :=format('%s:%s',[EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPServer,EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPPort]);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.host := EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPServer;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Port := StrToInt(EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPPort);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.DefaultPort := 0;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    Idmessage1 := TIDMessage.Create;

    try
      with Idmessage1 do
      begin
        Subject := EmailSendOptions.sOSubject;
        From.Address := EmailSendOptions.sOSenderEmail;
        From.Name := EmailSendOptions.sOSenderName;
        for t := 0 to EmailSendOptions.slORecipients.count -1 do
          with Recipients.Add do
              Address := EmailSendOptions.slORecipients[t];
        with ReplyTo.Add do
          Address := EmailSendOptions.sOReplyToEmailAddress;
        for t := 0 to EmailSendOptions.slOAttachments.Count - 1 do
          Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MessageParts, EmailSendOptions.slOAttachments[t]);
        for t := 0 to EmailSendOptions.slOAttachments.Count - 1 do //2nd copy of attachment for debugging
          Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MessageParts, EmailSendOptions.slOAttachments[t]);
        Body.Assign(EmailSendOptions.slOBodyMessage);
      end;

      IdIMAP41:= TIdIMAP4.create;
      try
        IdIMAP41.intercept := imaplog;
        imaplog.active := true;
        IdIMAP41.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
        IdIMAP41.Host := EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPServer;
        IdIMAP41.Password := EmailSendOptions.sOPassword;
        IdIMAP41.Port := StrToInt(EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPPort);
        IdIMAP41.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
        IdIMAP41.Username := EmailSendOptions.sOUserName;

        IdIMAP41.Connect;
        IdIMAP41.SelectMailbox(EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPFolder);
        IdIMAP41.AppendMsg(EmailSendOptions.sPOPIMAPFolder,IdMessage1);
        IdIMAP41.Disconnect;

        Result := True;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(IdIMAP41);
      end;

      Result := True;

    finally
      Idmessage1.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You didn't provide any code that configures your variable `Info` in the IMAP code block. Could you check the value of `Info.ContentType` before you pass it to `AppendMsg`? The builder's method `FillMessage` should set its value to `multipart/mixed`.

Comment: `TIdMessageBuilderHTML` fills a `TIdMessage` with content, it has no effect on how `TIdSMTP` and `TIdIMAP4` send that content. However, `TIdMessage` re-generates its email data dynamically each time it is sent/saved, and `AppendMsg()` is complex due to its `AAlternativeHeaders` parameter and that IMAP requires the email's size be sent before the data, whereas SMTP does not. Assuming `IdMessage1` and `Info` are the same object, there's no guarantee that SMTP and IMAP will receive the *exact* same data, but it should be *close* (differences being the `Date` header, MIME boundaries, etc)...

Comment: ... Without seeing the raw email data, it is hard to say why emails sent via IMAP are not working correctly.  You should capture the raw email data in both `TIdSMTP` and `TIdIMAP4` and compare them for differences. To perform that capture, you can assign one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to the `TIdSMTP.Intercept` and `TIdIMAP4.Intercept` properties. Also, which version of Delphi are you using, and are you using the Indy that shipped with it, or are you using an up-to-date version from Indy's online repo?

Comment: @Winsys11 You're not setting up the `TIdMessage` correctly, as you're not using the MessageBuilder in your new IMAP code. Attachments are present, so the body text should be in a `TIdText` object in the `TIdMessage.MessageParts`. `TIdMessage` will try to correct that internally by default, but best not to make that mistake to begin with. Also, you're not setting the `TIdMessage.ContentType`. `TIdMessage` should be setting a `ContentType` for you when attachments are present, but your output suggests that isn't happening. You should be able to use the same `TIdMessage` for both SMTP and IMAP.

Comment: @Winsys11 Also, unrelated to `TIdMessage`, DO NOT set the SSLIOHandler's `Destination`, `Host`, `Port`, and `DefaultPort` properties manually, let Indy handle those for you. And DO NOT set its `SSLOptions.Method` to `sslvSSLv23` manually, use the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` instead and let Indy handle the `SSLOptions.Method` for you.